# SQL Loader - Don't require a dat file

Tags: sql-loader

I am trying to insert a record into a table. I dont need to access a dat file, because all values are either constants or generated in the control file itself.

An example would be -

```
OPTIONS(LOAD=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE table_name
(P_ID CONSTANT 202, NAME CONSTANT "ABC", NUM CONSTANT 1, CREATED_BY CONSTANT "DEF",
CREATION_DATE EXPRESSION "current_timestamp(6)")
```

However, when I execute the sqlldr command for the above ctl file, I am getting the following error -

```
SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (<file_name>.dat)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please show us the commandline you use to run sqlldr

Answer (score 2):

I tink you need to correct yor controlfile:

> LOAD DATA
>
> **INFILE ***

Comment: @downvoter why this answer has -2 reputation? I know that it is the correct solution